# Trying to make a robloxsearch command with RBLX Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, roblox

I am trying to use ROBLOX's API to make a `;rs` command but it isn't going so well.

Using request-promise I tried searching and it brought me this error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

I have reviewed questions on here before and answered some. If this helps, I am using discord.js-commando for my command handler.

Here is the part the error is coming from:

```
let editMsg = await msgObject.reply(
  ":triumph: Finding ROBLOX Account, give me a second!"
);
let rs = await request({
    uri: `https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/search?keyword=${idk}&limit=10`,
    simple: false,
    json: true
});


if (rs.userFacingMessage == "Something went wrong"){
    if(rs.code == 5){
        editMsg.edit("Sorry , We couldn't process your search! The username you provided has been filtered!");
    }
    if(rs.code == 6){
        editMsg.edit("Sorry , We couldn't process your search! The username you provided is too short!");
    }
}else {
    let user = JSON.parse(rs)
    msgObject.reply(user)
}
```

Here is a [PasteBin link](https://pastebin.com/FQ1rvn36) if you need to see the whole `run()` method.

Comment: hey. could you provide the code you're using please?

Comment: Where is `data` and `Data` coming from? Are these two different variables or a single one?

Comment: @Daerendor The code is specified if you click ;rs command but I'll update it so you can see it without clicking a link.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Thanks for asking that but, thats not relevant for the error I was talking about. Not trying to be rude but I want an answer for the part of code I put above.

Comment: @coolgamerboy sry i thought it was alink to somethign else. Have you tried logging rs? What does it give? On what line is the error thrown?

Comment: @Daerendor, no I haven't heard of logging a command, can you tell me what that is or give me a link to what 'ur talking about?         let user = JSON.parse(rs)
        msgObject.reply(user) its either the variable or the reply not sure.

Comment: By logging rs I mean logging the variable rs, the API response, so you can see what data is coming into your application and then more easily debug.

Comment: @Daerendor yeah, i have and it either gives me undefined or object.
i didnt console.log it tho u can see it in my code above

Comment: i could use some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) with the option `json: true` automatically parses the JSON string in the response. It means your variable `rs` is already an object, not a JSON string.

The [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method parses a JSON string, so when you try to parse an object, Node.js converts it to a string first (`[object Object]`). The first character is `[` which is valid JSON, but the second one (the letter `o`) is not, so you receive a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.

Try it out below:

```js
const rs = {
  previousPageCursor: null
}
try {
  console.log(JSON.parse(rs))
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message)
}
```

The API endpoint at `https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/search?keyword=${idk}&limit=10` returns an object, so you can't simply send it as-is in a reply. You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to create a string from that object, or you can get an array of users from `rs.data`.

If you want to return a single user, you can either grab the first item (`rs.data[0]`) from that array, or use the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find one that matches your keyword:

```js
} else {
  const user = rs.data[0]
  msgObject.reply(`\`\`\`${JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}\`\`\``)
}
```

```js
} else {
  const user = rs.data.find((u) => u.name === idk)
  msgObject.reply(`\`\`\`${JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}\`\`\``)
}
```

[image]

<sub><sup>PS: Next time when you don't want to be rude, don't write *"Not trying to be rude but I want an answer [...]"*</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I'm fairly new to posting on stackoverflow so I thank you for the feedback, I'll try my best to be professional.

Comment: This solution fixes my object problem but now I get a new problem, undefined" I put this into a editor with syntax highlighting and nothing is wrong. I defined description. I need help!

Comment: Nope, no error messages. the name just pops up as undefined, and when i copy the id and paste it into roblox it links me to an account named undefined. it looks like username is undefined so its sending a request to roblox to search for undefined.

Comment: What do you use as the `idk` keyword?

Comment: I changed it from idk to username, full code is in the pastebin, should answer that question above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230520/discussion-between-cool-gamerboy-and-zsolt-meszaros).

Answer (score -2):

```js
const rs = {
  previousPageCursor: null
}
try {
  console.log(JSON.parse(rs))
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message)
}
```

Comment: You should not do this. You are just coping a part of the previous answer and adding it as a comment with not additional info.